# Rasa threshold implementation

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

I wanted an implementation where if the confidence of an intent is below say, 0.6 then a particular action to be invoked and perform an API call, from there on I want to be able to either execute custom action or continue with the intent which was resolved in the first place based on some condition.

Comment: Although, I haven't worked with the confidence of intents. I have a general idea of how to do what you want to do. We need to use the tracker.events in our actions.py file and manipulate it accordingly. 

For starters, you should add these in one of your actions:
conversation = tracker.events
print(conversation)

Comment: After you print the tracker.events, all the information you need for every event should print on the console that is running your actions file. And one of the information that its gonna print is the confidence of the intents. I guess this is where you can branch out from and hopefully do what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please be sure to share your experience and findings in this question, so I could also learn a thing or two from it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably try take a look into this [Rule Policy](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/policies#rule-policy). You can always modify the action that is specified here and put the conditions that you wish to perform under the same action.